# How to offset lag function by a dynamic value?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table as below. I'm trying to derive column `activity_role_adjusted` from column `activity_role`. I've tried using `lag()` but my offset is dynamic. The required value may be one row above or 5 rows above for a given partition.

Logic for column `activity_role_adjusted`:

- if `activity_role <> 'Other'`, then `activity_role`
- if `activity_role = 'Other'` then the last value in previous months that was not equal to 'Other'
- if all rows above are 'Other', then retain 'Other'

For every employee there will be only 8 rows of data. Jan to Aug.

| employee_login | month | activity_role | activity_role_adjusted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Jan | Other | Other |
| abc | Feb | Source1 | Source1 |
| abc | Mar | Other | Source1 |
| abc | Apr | Other | Source1 |
| abc | May | Other | Source1 |
| abc | Jun | Source1 | Source1 |
| abc | Jul | Source2 | Source2 |
| abc | Aug | Other | Source2 |

Comment: Please remember to put defining info the question. Hidden away in comments won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift's window functions (including [`lag()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html)) support the `IGNORE NULLS` clause. You should be able to work with this:

```sql
SELECT *
     , CASE
          WHEN activity_role = 'Other'
          THEN COALESCE(lag(NULLIF(activity_role, 'Other')) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY employee_login ORDER BY to_timestamp('Feb', 'Mon'))
                     , 'Other')
          ELSE activity_role
       END AS activity_role_adjusted
FROM   tbl;
```

Using `to_timestamp()` to coerce your awkward month names into something we can order by. (Reshift doesn't seem to have the simpler `to_date()`.)

`NULLIF()` to replace 'Other' with `NULL`, which is skipped this way.

Finally, `COALESCE()` to default to 'Other' after all, if we find nothing else.

Aside:
Redshift for once supports a standard SQL feature that [Postgres doesn't](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html): `IGNORE NULLS`. Who would have thought? :)

Comment: Thank you... Was able to tweak it and it worked great for me!!

Comment: Tweks were still required?

Comment: Yes... but your code was perfect for the ask. The tweak was simply because I found a column with the date instead of the month string. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Miggah: If that answers your question properly, consider accepting the answer.